# javascript iterate through form elements to find input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, loops, input

I've been looking through and haven't really found a solution yet, so I ask.

I have a shopping cart that needs to confirm that the item that is being added already exists and asks if user still wants to add.

The code I have tried does find and asks the question, however it still submits and adds the selected item.

```
// check if item exists
$(".add_to_order").on("click", function() {
    var current_id = $(this).data("id");
    return $(".order_list input").each(function() {
        if ( current_id == $(this).val() ) {
            return confirm('Item exists, still want to add?');
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (CodeIgniter) / HTML (Bootstrap)

```
<?php if ($products) {
    foreach($products as $product){ ?>
        <form action="/orders/add_to_order" method="get">
            <button class="add_to_order" type="submit" data-id="<?php echo $product->id; ?>">Add to Cart</button>
        </form>
<?php } } ?>
```

Cart

```
<form action="/orders/send" method="post" id="order">
    <?php foreach($order_products as $order_product) { ?>
        <input class="added_product" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $order_product->product_id; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    <button type="submit">Order</button>
</form>
```

I chose to make the product ID hidden.

Thank you.

Comment: can you include html?and create snippet?

Comment: Does the confirm work? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: remove the return statement in return $(".order_list input").each(function() and try

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya tried, still submits

Comment: @Jonathan added the extra code. tried your solution below, still submits the form.

Comment: @ChuckK I'm sorry, I think I made a mistake. If you look at my edit, the ternary condition `(confirmed)` should actually be `(!confirmed)`. I haven't tested it yet though, but I believe the logic is sound...

Comment: @Jonathan yeah. i found the solution.

Comment: @ChuckK I'm glad my answer helped (if it did, please accept)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

AFAIK, jQuery's `.each()` function doesn't return a value.

When you are doing:

```
return $(".order_list input").each(function() {
    if ( current_id == $(this).val() ) {
        return confirm('Item exists, still want to add?');
    }
});
```

the inner return just returns to the `.each()`, but its value doesn't go to the `return`.

---

**SOLUTION**

I think the easiest way to solve this would be to set a variable `confirmed` and use it like so:

```
var confirmed = true;
return $(".order_list input").each(function() {
    if ( current_id == $(this).val() ) {
        confirmed = (!confirmed) ? false : confirm('Item exists, still want to add?');
    }
});
return confirmed;
```

This will start with `confirmed` as true, and if a single `confirm()` is pressed as false (if the user cancels), then `confirmed` will stay false.

Comment: i believe the inner return is just a confirmation and there should still be a condition for that. if confirm do this if not do that..just my thought..without seeing all the relevant code this is hard

Comment: @guradio yeah, extra code would help. But if you look at my update, I think this would be better for confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...

```
$(".add_to_order").on("click", function(e) {
    var current_id = $(this).data("id");
    $(".order_list input").each(function() {
        if ( current_id == $(this).val() ) {
            if (confirm('Item exists, still want to add?') == false)
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```